# Baking Glass and Glossy materials Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I'd like to ask if what is the proper method for baking textures in blender. I've followed a tutorial from blender guru but the problem is that the baked results for the glossy and glass materials are not as good as the original. Does this have something to do with how I bake them or something else?

**Baked**

[image: Baked Texture]

**Original**

[image: Not Baked]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The point of baking is that it stores the color that the object finally gets as a texture. This means that it is suitable for things like ambient occlusion, shadows, basically everything that remains exactly the same for the entire shot. However, because of the way baking works, it is completely unsuitable for things that change depending on the camera angle, like reflextions. What you could do is use a combination of baking and a regular material for the reflections.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response, but is there any way to like bake the textures as seen from the camera? like from the camera's point of view? @Ezra

Comment: @Nerdicon - to avoid misconceptions: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to recreate the BlenderGuru image or do you want to bake textures for a game asset?

Comment: Well I followed the tutorial to bake the textures for a game asset (unity), since unity doesn't seem to support nodes. I followed the tutorial thinking that the material would look like the original, the image above is just an example from when I tried to bake textures for glass vases. @metaphor_set

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Baking for RT Render Engines explained

One of the common misconceptions about baking is that people think they can use a render engine to "bake" materials for game assets.

In reality you can bake **only certain aspects of a material** into a texture. These are obviously diffuse maps, normal maps, displacement maps,  ambient occlusion maps and certain hybrid forms of them ("albedo" as a new term for "diffuse + light/shadow values", for example). Furthermore you can bake certain "helper maps" to help a RT render engine to generate physically based or dynamic aspects, like specularity and lightmaps.

Specularity maps are black and white or greyscale images that are are processed by any real-time render engine where black is interpreted as non-specular while white represents the opposite on that scale. They work, similar to normal and displacement maps, as non-color maps.

Lightmaps are similar to ao maps a static representation of light and shadow and their primary use is to reduce the GPU load on shadow calculation.

**Other material aspects like transparency, translucency, reflection and refraction of glass-like materials cannot be "pre-baked"**, since they depend on the render engine's capabilities and techniques to generate them. If your game render engine is capable to recreate these effects, they have to be created in the game engine's material editor.

**If this explanation answers your question, please mark it as accepted.**

Comment: Thanks! very helpful explanation, really... thank you. Um... there's one more thing that i'd like to ask about baking, I've read something on POV based baking? it that something I should take note of?

Comment: @Nerdicon - if you plan to use the objects as game assets, it depends on the style of your game. POV baking creates static effects and in a real time rendering engine you most certainly will change the point of view, if you do not use a fixed camera position.

Comment: So POV is just like those static backgrounds on some 2D games?