# Diffuse baking - extremly weird result (cycles)

Tags: texture-baking

I try to bake the diffuse map of my box model in **cycles render engine**, but I get extremly weird results:

I made a short video:
https://youtu.be/bwoLJ8psZ2E

1. This is my model:

[image]

2. it is a model which consists of multiple smaller models which I have joined at the end, thus it has multiple materials:

[image]

3. First I created a new UV-Map and choosed Smart UV-Layout.

[image]

[image]

4. Then I created a new texture in the UV-Panel

[image]

5. Next I hit bake:

[image]

6. This is the result:

[image]

7. ...and if I select the original UV-Map then it looks like this now:

[image]

8. I am not sure why this does not bake as expected.

If I do the same method with another model which has only one material, then it works without problems.

Comment: What happens if you uncheck clear in the bake settings?

Comment: did you assign the new UV map to be used with the baked image?

Comment: @cegaton, Im not sure, I did all the steps precisley like you see here or in the video.

Comment: @Brenticus, clear is creating an alpha mask on every part which is not painted.

Comment: On the step 2 try removing empty material slot

Comment: I tried it. The resulting texture looks different, but the problem itself was not solved with this method. But I already solved it, see my answer below.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake. Cycles bakes into image texture node currently selected so material must have it. Empty material slot is something better to be deleted regardless.

Comment: I was reading the cycles baking chapter in the official documentation but there was no word about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, I had to add the texture `bakeResult0001` created at *step #4* **to** **each material** as **none connected** image texture node, I also had to only check "color" in the bake settings, otherwise weird black spots were baked onto the texture.

[image]

I created a video: https://youtu.be/nOvtGUgWCA0