# Baking normal maps from Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map

How can I bake a normal map from Cycles material? I need to export model to another program, but in Cycles I can bake normal only from high poly model, from material I cant.

Thank you.

Comment: something like this ->> https://github.com/Secrop/ShaderNodesExtra/blob/master/Nodes/ShaderNodeNormalBake.py ??

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture