# Metallic and Specular bake with Blender

Tags: texture-baking, pbr

I want to export a PBR asset from Blender to  UE4, but for the metallic parts I obviously need the specularity or metallic maps which are not in baking options of cycles. I've seen people talking about using emission or using Blender Internal and 'draw' it manually, also generating it with painting software because its just a black and white scale I think. I  can't find a clear answer to this or a proper way to proceed.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Where should the emit be in this case? It's a steel material.
[image]

Also, the object has different metallic materials, how should I integrate them into 1 and only map? 
Thanks

Comment: what's the problem of using emission pass to bake them? Did you try it? Where did it fail? Can you provide more detail to help? I can point you in this direction otherwise: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91784/7777 (1st method is the emit pass)