# baking a procedurally textured sphere to equirectangular normal map

Tags: baking, normal-map

I'm trying to bake a prodecurally textured sphere to an equirectangular normal map.
I followed this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91784/75987 and it seems to work well.

But when I bake the normal map and apply it to a simple UV sphere I always get some lighting artifacts. The same happens when I just use the normal map that was provided in that answer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuurB.jpg). 
You can see the artifacts on this screenshot:
[image]

When I change e.g. the rotation in the mapping node the artifact stays in place though, while the texture rotates accordingly. This is very confusing to me because if the artifacts are caused by the normal map shouldn't it follow the mapping rotation also?

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.
How can I get a clean result without artifacts?

Comment: Change Color in the Image Texture with normal map to Non-Color. Other than that as you baked on the unwrapped mesh use UV output socket to actually use UV map used when baking

Comment: Oh wow, if I change to non-color it seems to work perfectly at first glance. Thank you very much! You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @MrZak Thank you - "Non-Color" worked perfectly, but why? Also, if I plan to use the texture for Unity, will I run into the same issue?