# I have version 2.74. Is there a way to put the colors in the UV/Image Editor I'm not using a texture?

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

Is there a way to make the colors into the UV/image editor I'm not using a texture But I want to be able to export the image with the colors because I can't change them where I'm exporting it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture/

Comment: Do the linked posts answer your questions, or are you still having difficulties?