# Using Blender 2.8 texture nodes with Unity

Tags: texturing, unity

Does anybody know the best way to get a procedurally generated texture (made by using the node system in EEVEE) to work inside of Unity? I have an object that I made and textured in Blender but cannot get the textures to show in Unity. I have exported the file as both an .fbx and .glTF and Unity shows the texture for neither.

Comment: No way. You can only bake the textures in cycles and save them as pictures, then use them in Unity.

Comment: thank you for the reply, is there a direction you can point me to for that?

Comment: Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture/91784 also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509