# How to convert materials into textures in EEVEE?

Tags: texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

So, I made a very complex material (in my opinion) in EEVEE, using certain nodes that only apply to EEVEE like the *Shader to RGB* node.

I've come across certain tutorials in which they transform materials into textures, but they're using Blender 2.79 and below.

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqGablXLduI)

[Stack Exchange Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture)

Also, while trying to find some solution, i came across something they called "Principled Baker" in which I suppose it's an add-on to bake textures from the Principled Shader. The problem is, by my understanding, the Principled Baker only works with Cycles.

[Principled Baker](https://blenderartists.org/t/principled-baker-bake-pbr-textures-with-a-few-clicks-for-2-80-and-2-79/1102187)

So, I decided to ask "Is there any way to convert the material I have into textures?".

I'm not an expert on textures but I'd say it's probably albedo/base color, roughness and normal.

I'll leave my blend file of the object in question.

[Blender File](https://mega.nz/#!yok3AayL!cYPdAXoo63DB3JYaUGBRsgUYSO5hZUWnvdI3b9vJpi4)

Thank you for your time and hope to hear good news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of July of this year, you can't bake Eevee-specific elements to textures, since Eevee itself doesn't support baking.

There's a discussion about this on the blender community page

https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/X0dbbc/

The main takeaway from the original post there is;

"Baking isn't currently available in Eevee in any form." -jpgarsemailbox

If you have an object that uses non-Eevee-specific nodes, you could bake it in Cycles (et al) and bring it back into Eevee. You might even be able to bake everything *except* the Eevee-specific parts, then layer those on top after backing in another renderer.

Comment: Not the answer I was expecting but a straight forward answer.

Thank you very much