# Is it possible to turn the shader nodes into textures?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I know this is an odd question I make models in blender for my game looking at the procedural nodes it seems way easier to just make the textures using the nodes in blender rather than fixing textures to match my UV's or vice versa. I was hoping there was a way to export them like a texture into ue4 or bake them into the shape of the model at least.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE :). I believe [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/90096/78972) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I must of missed that post!