# I can't handle the textures for roblox

Tags: mesh

in roblox I can use only one texture per object, but I don't know how to do this because I make my objects with more textures than one

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture/91784#91784