# Generate a new PNG texture file after applying color ramp node

Tags: texturing, blend-files

[image]

Does someone know if it's possible export/save the material PNG file with the ColorRamp node applied to it?

I want to use the original .png file, apply the color ramp to it, and save it as a new .png file.

I need to recreate the material on UE4 and having the texture with the ramp applied would be very useful.

Thank you.

Comment: You can also try "baking" the texture to an image. In this linked answer you can try to 1st method.. It always works for me. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91763/50125

Answer (score 1):

Just put the texture to a plane, don't use a shader but just plug it after the colorramp to the material output. Then just render it out (with camera located/rotated to the plane) -> done